# JavaFx Set Tableview Cell Background Color Dynamically

Tags: java, javafx-2

I want to add color to the color cell of the rows dynamically when ADD button is clicked. I am not able to change the background color of the cell. Please see the image for reference. 
Am not able to achieve that with the help of code.
Thanks for help in advance.

Snippet adding values to table :

```
     @FXML
     private void addEntity() {

      data.add(new Inventory(codeTemp.getText(), articleNameTemp.getText(), Integer.parseInt(amountTemp.getText()), dcTemp.isSelected() ? true:false, stTemp.isSelected()?true:false, Utilities.toRGBCode(colorTemp.getValue()), informationTemp.getText(), data.size()+1));
      inventoryTable.setItems(data);

     }
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did with the help of a callback on the column.

```
        Callback<TableColumn<Inventory, String>, TableCell<Inventory, String>> cellFactory =
        new Callback<TableColumn<Inventory, String>, TableCell<Inventory, String>>() {
            public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
                TableCell cell = new TableCell<Person, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        setText(empty ? null : getString());
                        setStyle("-fx-background-color:"+getString());
                    }

                    private String getString() {
                        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
                    }
                };


                return cell;
            }
        };
```

[image]

Comment: I have a similar problem (exact same code actually) however "item" is null all the time. Anybody know why this is?

Comment: forget about adding cell factory to the column. Are you able to add data to the table?

Comment: Yes, i have three String columns which contain data

Comment: Have you added the cellfactory to the column? like : `column.setCellFactory(cellFactory`